# How can I make my app available only for mobiles devices & 7-inch tablets, but not for 9 & 10-inch tablets? Please see details

Tags: android, mobile, android-manifest, android-screen-support, androiddesignsupport

I'm developing a **material design** app.

**I want my app to be available for only mobile devices & 7-inch tablet, but not for 9 & 10-inch tablets. So that only mobile & 7-inch tablet users can see my app in play store.**

I really do not know how to achieve this task!

Please let me know.

Sorry for such a bad format of this question, but I really want to know!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the`<supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
                  android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
                  android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
                  android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
                  android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>`